# Binding to the combobox control template item failed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm using the combobox and binding through List values as like below

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="testCombo" Margin="67,48,184,204">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ComboBox},Mode=OneWay,Path=SelectedItem}" Width="100" Height="50" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>            
    </ComboBox>
```

binding data like below in c#

```
      IList<string> objLoadData = new List<String> { "Ramesh", "Suresh" };
      testCombo.DataContext = objLoadData;
```

I tried to bind the data into textbox, but I couldn't. How do bind datas to textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

Inside constuctor

```
testCombo.DataContext = this;
testCombo.ItemsSource = objLoadData;
```

In XAML

```
   <ComboBox Name="testCombo" Width="100" Height="50" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" Height="50" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: can you explani why we want to set both datacontext and itemsource in code iteself ?

Comment: `ItemsSource` tells from where we getting the items to the combobox. Moreover what are the items in the combobox.

Comment: Now, I understood very clearly, then this below also working. Thank you so much for your explanation

   testCombo.DataContext = objLoadData;

   <ComboBox Name="testCbo1" Margin="67,48,184,204" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

Answer (score 1):

If your list is just strings just `Text="{Binding}"` should work

You should think about using an `ObservableCollection` for your `ItemsSource` as it will automaticly update the `ComboBox` when Items change (add/remove etc)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" Margin="67,48,184,204">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="50" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _comboItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboItems.Add("Stack");
        ComboItems.Add("Overflow");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItems
    {
        get { return _comboItems; }
        set { _comboItems = value; }
    }
}
```

If you want to use a `TextBox` in the `ComboBox` you will probably want to use an object as the backing store for the string that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` this way eveyything is updated and kept in sync.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" Margin="67,48,184,204">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" Height="50" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _comboItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Stack" });
        ComboItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Overflow" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> ComboItems
    {
        get { return _comboItems; }
        set { _comboItems = value; }
    }
}

public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```